# Comment expliquer l'usage de « an » vs « en »?

Tags: orthographe

J'ai toujours eu de la difficulté à démêler les graphies « an » et  « en » dans l’orthographe des mots. Je sais qu'il existe [un ensemble de règles (relativement complexe)](http://66.46.185.79/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?id=3716) régissant leurs usages, mais j'ai encore de la difficulté à les assimiler.

Maintenant, je dois expliquer à mon fils de 7 ans l'usage de ces graphies lors de l’étude de ses leçons de vocabulaire. J'en suis à lui dire de simplement mémoriser quelle graphie utiliser pour chaque mot.

Est-ce qu'il existe une façon plus intelligente pour apprendre à utiliser correctement ces graphies ?

Comment: Pas facile avec un anfent de 7 ens.

Comment: I do not understand this question at all. Is the question asking why some words are spelled with *an* while others are spelled with *en*?

Comment: @Aerovistae Exactement.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ce serait miraculeux qu'il en existe, puisque ces graphies différentes sont en général des résidus de prononciations différentes.

En simplifiant beaucoup : à l'origine — du latin jusqu'au Français du onzième siècle — les *an* se prononçaient [an] (comme *anne*) et les *en* [ɛn] (comme *aine*). Vers le onzième siècle l'influence de la nasale [n] les a déformés en [ɑ̃n] et [ɛ̃n] (penser *an* et *in* avec l'accent du sud de la France) puis en [ɑ̃] et [ɑ̃], la disparition du [n] se situant vers le dix-septième siècle. La graphie n'a pas évolué à la même vitesse, d'où la difficulté.

Cela dit, on peut peut-être quand même imaginer une *rule of thumb* pour s'en souvenir.

Comment: Donc au départ les français prononçaient correctement? Comme en anglais :)

Comment: @Benjol: J'ai envie de plussoyer et de moinssoyer ton commentaire en même temps. C'est intéressant, mais je ne suis pas d'accord avec les insinuations :-p