# Pourquoi certains « e » se prononcent-ils « a » ?

Tags: prononciation, histoire, voyelles, nasalisation

*Femme*, *évidemment*, *solennellement*, *fréquemment*, *différemment*, et il y en a sûrement de nombreux autres.

Y a-t-il une raison derrière ces *e* prononcés *a*, et qui doivent rendre fou les personnes essayant d'apprendre notre langue ?

Ou bien peut-être est-ce juste une déformation ou une mauvaise habitude de prononciation ?

Comment: Je crois qu'il s'agit de /ɑ̃/ écrit _en_ qui ont perdu leur prononciation nasale et sont donc devenus /a/.

Comment: C'est surtout pour « femme » que c'est énervant, car les autres semblent suivre une règle, de mémoire (les « -emment »).

Comment: 'Femme' est une exception qui vient de 'femina', mais en effet tout est du fait de la prononciation nasale.

Comment: Raisons historiques d'évolution de la langue. On pourra lire *Phonétique historique du français et notions de phonétique générale*, à feuilleter [ici](http://books.google.fr/books?hl=fr&id=mP4JUXoFLBoC&q=nasalisation#v=snippet&q=nasalisation&f=false) et en particulier le chapitre III *les voyelles suivies d'une consonne nasale* (p.204).  Quelques phrases de résumé [ici](http://bbouillon.free.fr/univ/hl/Fichiers/Cours/orthog.htm).

Comment: @Laure, tu devrais faire de ce commentaire une réponse complète. J'ajouterais qu'avant de lire cette question, je ne savais pas qu'on prononçait un a dans *solennel*.

Comment: @Circeus: peut-être que ça se prononce différemment au Québec ?

Comment: @Jahnux73 je ne comprend pas bien le rapport entre _femina_ et la prononciation du _e_ en _a_ dans femme. A moins que la prononciation latine soit très différente de la française, je n'en sais que trop rien :/

Comment: @Fractaliste Je ne me rappelle plus la source, mais je vais raconter cette petite histoire. Il y a longtemps, les gens cultivés parlaient latin, et utiliser le mot 'femina'. Seulement, en prononcant ce mot rapidement et regulierement dans le langage populaire, la première syllabe vient alors à se prononcer 'fa'. Je vais essayer de trouver des sources afin de les partager.

Comment: @Laure Non. P-ê que ce /a/ tends à se réduire en "schwa" à cause de son emplacement dans le mot ou d'un phénomène d'[harmonie vocalique](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonie_vocalique) naturelle, mais je ne crois pas que ce soit une prononciation admise.

Comment: @Jahnux73 La réponse de Laure est confirmée par mes références (ainsi que des prononciations comme *minme* pour *même*): c'est le passage par la voyelle nasale (influencée par la présence de deux consonnes nasales issues du latin) qui est à l'origine de ce /a/. Je lui ai suggéré d'en faire une réponse au propre pour ne pas en prendre le crédit.

Comment: @Circeus: Oui, j'ai vu, c'est en préparation, ça demande un peu de temps mais ça va venir. Chapeau pour ton fair-play. - (*Tiens ils ont oublié celui-là*)

Comment: En passant, voir http://french.stackexchange.com/questions/1474/comment-expliquer-lusage-de-an-vs-en

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Cette graphie est due à la nasalisation, puis dénasalisation de la voyelle placée devant la consonne nasale [m]. Ce phénomène a touché toutes les voyelles placées devant des consonnes nasales.

L'explication la plus simple que j'ai trouvée est [ici](http://bbouillon.free.fr/univ/hl/Fichiers/Cours/orthog.htm) :

> Les consonnes nasales doubles nn et mm sont des graphies historiques
>   ; elles correspondent à une prononciation : voyelle nasalisée +
>   consonne nasale (une année [ãne], un homme [õm], une femme [fãm], la
>   grammaire [gRãmeR]). La voyelle, nasalisée au XI, s'est ensuite
>   dénasalisée, aux XV<sup>e</sup> - XVII<sup>e</sup> siècles, le plus
>   tardivement pour le on [õ]. On a donc d'abord écrit an pour [ã] + 2ème
>   consonne n.

Pour une explication plus scientifique on peut regarder *Introduction à la phonétique historique du français*. (Annick Englebert) que j'essaie de résumer ici :

La nasalisation est un phénomène qui s'est produit du X<sup>e</sup> siècle. Il a affecté les voyelles et les diphtongues suivies des nasales [m] [n] ou [ɲ].

Processus :
La présence d'une consonne nasale a sur la voyelle qui précède trois effets successifs.

- Au VII<sup>e</sup> siècle les voyelles simples entravées par une consonne finale nasale se ferment, ainsi
  [ɛn] >[en], [ɔn]>[on].
- Entre le X<sup>e</sup> et le XIV<sup>e</sup> siècles, la voyelle qui précède la consonne nasale se nasalise (anticipation de l'abaissement du voile du palais).
  Les premiers phénomènes touchés par les nasalisations sont les voyelles et diphtongues plus ouvertes, à savoir les voyelles [a] et [e] et les diphtongues correspondantes. Les voyelles fermées suivront.
- À l'achèvement de la phase de nasalisation, toutes les voyelles sont nasalisées devant les consonnes nasales qui subsistent ; la séquence voyelle nasale+consonne nasale est donc systématique (ce dont des graphies tendent à rendre compte en doublant la nasale (nn/mm) : feme/femme.

À l'issue de la phase de nasalisation des voyelles, un des deux phénomènes d'articulation nasale va être éliminé :

- la consonne si elle est en position faible
- la voyelle si elle est en position forte (syllabe ouverte ou initiale). On est dans ce cas pour femme : fémĩnam >femme

En ancien français les copistes notaient la nasalisation soit en usant d'un tilde (~) sur la voyelle, soit en doublant la consonne intervocalique ; le doublement de la consonne a été conservé dans certaines graphies modernes.

Comment: Bonjour, Qu'en est-il pour le mot "flemme" ? Il y a bien 2 "m"
Idem pour le mot gemme. Auriez-vous une explication? Cordialement.

Comment: @Molière If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](http://french.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context.

Comment: @Molière Dans « flemme »  et « gemme » il n'y a pas eu de nasalisation de la voyelle.

Comment: @Molière To elaborate on this, flemme is an 13th Century borrowing from the Italian *flemma*, after the nasalisation of the low vowels. Gemme had the alternate orthography "jame" in Old French, and was probably affected by the same sound changes as "femme". The modern pronunciation with an /ɛ/ instead of the expected /a/ probably reflects a borrowing of the Occitan cognate *gema*.

Comment: La tilde pour noter la nasalisation, en fait, c'est un peu l'inverse : la tilde notait souvent la double consonne qui a été ensuite nasalisée. Même chose qu'en espagnol où la double consonne N a donné lieu à la prononciation actuelle de ñ.

Answer (score 3):

Je connais une explication sur seulmement  « femme » dans ce livre de McWhorter, J. [PhD  Linguistics (Stanford)](https://americanstudies.columbia.edu/people/john-h-mcwhorter). [*The Power of Babel* (2003)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/006052085X). Consulter la p. 22.

> [image]

Answer (score 2):

Le groupe EMM dans 'femme' se prononçait anciennement comme dans 'emmagasiner', et de même le ENN de 'solennel' se prononçait jadis comme dans 'enneigé'. Il en était de même des groupe ANN dans 'canne' ou 'année', ONN dans 'bonne' etc. En français moderne, le voyelles nasales se sont pour la plupart dénasalisées devant une consonne nasale (m ou n), sauf là où (comme dans les mots 'emmagasiner' ou 'enneigé' déjà cités) le locuteur avait conscience de la présence du préfixe en-. Ainsi en est-on venu à prononcer 'cane', 'ané', 'bone', et de même 'fame' et 'solanel'.
Le même développement phonétique explique la prononciation (aujourd'hui vieillie) 'indane' pour 'indemne', ainsi que l'amuïssement du M dans 'damné', 'condamner' 'automne'.

Comment: Très intéressant, j'ignorais cette ancienne prononciation pour *indemne*. On peut noter tout de même que certains accents prononce encore aujourd'hui "an-née".