# Les voyelles nasales avant des consonnes nasales

Tags: phonétique, passé-simple, nasalisation

Au passé simple, il y a beaucoup de formes qu'on prononce avec une voyelle nasale avant une consonne nasale, comme:

> nous vînmes = /nu vɛ̃m/

Mais je ne peux pas penser à d'autres exemples où on a un mot monosyllabique qui se termine avec une consonne nasale et possède une voyelle nasale. 
Selon le dictionnaire de rimes, toutes les rimes de « vînmes » sont des formes de « nous » au passé simple.

1. Est-ce que ce sont les seuls exemples? (On demande un seul mot, d'une seule syllabe, qui se termine par une consonne nasale et qui a une voyelle nasale aussi. Donc *mon_ami* ou *emmener* ne comptent pas — je pense qu'on dit aussi *mon_ami* avec une voyelle orale dans beaucoup de régions francophones.)
2. Si la réponse à (1) est affirmative. Puisque le passé simple n'est pas très courant, peut-on dire que ce son est un peu étrange aux oreilles francophones ? Est-ce qu'on le fait avec soin quand on lit des textes avec le passé simple, ou peut-on prononcer la voyelle sans nasalisation ?

Comment: La raison est ici: http://french.stackexchange.com/questions/8239/pourquoi-certains-e-se-prononcent-ils-a

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Il existe au moins 2 autres cas de voyelles explicitement nasales (et non accidentellement, comme dans la prononciation familière de *même* au Québec ou celle des voyelles nasales en fin de mot dans le Midi de la France, /lapɛ̃ŋ/ pour *lapin*): *mainmise* et *panmixie*.

Cette séquence phonétique est, pour les raisons expliquées dans la question  *[Pourquoi certains « e » se prononcent-ils « a » ?](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/8239/)*, extrêmement rare. Dans le cas de la conjugaison de *tenir* et *venir*, il est fort probable que ces voyelles, ainsi que décrit dans la réponse de Laure, aient été initialement dénasalisées, mais que la forte pression de l'analogie des formes du reste de la conjugaison ait provoqué la renasalisation. De mémoire, je ne crois pas qu'aucun verbe présente des voyelles différentes à ces deux personnes, et cette irrégularité était d'autant plus incongrue qu'à l'époque le passé simple était encore d'un emploi oral courant.

Pour *mainmise* et *panmixie*, c'est la composition, via un préfixe ou un mot composé qui est à l'origine de la combinaison, car elle n'est pas formellement interdite par la phonologie du français (contrairement à kn- en début de mot qu'on retrouve en allemand).