# femme - why pronounced but not spelt as "famme"

Tags: prononciation

I'm learning the French pronunciation rules, and noticed that the word *femme* doesn't follow common rules (where it should have been pronounced /fem/, not /fam/). I'm aware of a special rule where an E followed by two consonants is pronounced as `è` or `ê`, but it doesn't apply here. Can anyone clear my confusion?

Comment: Voir https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/8239/pourquoi-certains-e-se-prononcent-ils-a

Comment: "Femme" is clearly an exception word, we learn it as an exception when we are in schools as French kids. But, on the other end, the "emme" pronounced "am" is common in adverbs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can find several articles explaining this. For instance:

[Pourquoi certains « e » se prononcent-ils « a » ?](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/8239/pourquoi-certains-e-se-prononcent-ils-a)

https://www.orthodidacte.com/orthographe/prononciation-du-mot-femme/

https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/femme#Fran%C3%A7ais

Below there is the translation of the following article

https://www.pourquois.com/francais/pourquoi-e-femme-prononce-.html

> La langue française possède de nombreuses subtilités qu'il n'est pas
>   toujours facile de comprendre. Prenons l'exemple du mot "femme" dont
>   le premier "e" se prononce "a". Cela peut sembler tout à fait
>   illogique ! Et pourtant, c'est pour une bonne raison. Nous vous
>   expliquons pourquoi le "e" de femme se prononce "a" ?
>
> Si l'on prend le mot "femelle", on voit bien que toutes les lettres
>   sont formulées correctement. Aucune n'a l'air de se transformer en une
>   autre. Et pourtant, notre prononciation de "femme" n'est pas mauvaise.
>   Ou plutôt, elle l'était au tout début, mais cela s'est finalement
>   banalisé. En effet, à l'origine, il nous fallait prononcer ce terme
>   comme il était écrit. Cependant, la langue a évolué. Il n'était pas du
>   tout évident de le dire correctement, en respectant toutes les lettres
>   (essayez et vous verrez !). Le langage populaire l'a donc déformé au
>   fur et à mesure des années, afin de le rendre plus aisé à formuler. Le
>   son s'est ainsi transformé, et sa prononciation est devenue celle que
>   nous connaissons désormais. C'est pourquoi le "e" dans « femme » se prononce
>   "a". Mais qu'en est-il de l'écriture nous direz-vous ?
>
> Si la prononciation a évolué, ce n'est pas le cas de la graphie. Cela
>   est dû au fait qu'à l'époque de cette évolution, peu de gens savaient
>   lire. Ils n'était donc pas gênant que le mot ne reflète pas cette
>   dernière. De plus, seuls les érudits avaient accès à ce savoir, et ils
>   défendirent farouchement son écriture, afin qu'elle demeure comme elle
>   était. Ils souhaitaient conserver ses racines, puisque le terme « femme »
>   vient du latin « femina ».

The French language has many subtleties that are not always easy to understand. Take the example of the word "woman" whose first "e" is pronounced "a". This may seem completely illogical! And yet, it's for a good reason. We explain why the "e" in "woman" is pronounced "a".

If we take the word "female", we can see that all the letters are formulated correctly. None seem to turn into another. And yet, our pronunciation of "femme" is not bad. Or rather, it was so at the very beginning, but it finally became commonplace. Indeed, originally, we had to pronounce this term as it was written. However, the language has evolved. What the correct pronunciation could be was not at all obvious if you had to respect all the letters (try and you will see!). Popular language has thus distorted it over the years, in order to make it easier to formulate. The sound has changed, and its pronunciation has become the one we know now. This is why the "e" in "femme" is pronounced "a". But what about writing you will tell us?

If the pronunciation has evolved, it is not the case of the spelling. This is because at the time of this evolution, few people could read. So they were not annoyed by the word  not reflecting the latter. Moreover, only scholars had access to this knowledge, and they fiercely defended his writing so that he would remain as he was. They wanted to keep their roots, since the term "femme" comes from the Latin "femina".

Comment: Ah, so it's *en* pronouncing similarly to *en*, right?

Comment: I corrected some errors (you might agree or not with the corrections) but I must say that the French text is not too coherent: for instance I can't make a precise connection between « lettres fomulées correctement dans « female »» et « prononciation de « femme » pas mauvaise maintenant ».

Answer (score 4):

Cette prononciation bizarre est tout simplement le résultat d'une évolution populaire du langage parce que la présente prononciation aurait été trouvée plus facile qu'une prononciation qui correspondrait à « e »; voir cette explication : https://www.pourquois.com/francais/pourquoi-e-femme-prononce-.html.
Cependant on dit normalement « lemme », « gemme », et « flemme ».

On retrouve quand même cette prononciation « a » dans les adverbes.

- appar**e**mment, ard**e**mmemt, consci**e**mment, conséqu**e**mment, etc.